# OnClick Button in ListView is not working correct

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onclick

I have a listview in Fragment,where you can check items, and a button that shows what items are clicked. But when I uncheck items,and press button, it is still showing them as checked. What can solve a problem?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.feat, container, false);
     final ListView list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final Button button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    list.setItemChecked(4, true);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,items);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            switch (arg0.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    SparseBooleanArray a = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    if (checked(a) > 0) {
                        String vCheckedList = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                            if (a.valueAt(i) && i < list.getAdapter().getCount() && a.size() > 1)
                                vCheckedList += list.getAdapter().getItem(a.keyAt(i)) + "\n";
                            else if (a.valueAt(i))
                                vCheckedList += list.getAdapter().getItem(a.keyAt(i));
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), vCheckedList + " is checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        a.clear();
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "No Item is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

And here is xml:`

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="382dp">
</ListView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
```

`[image: Here is how it looks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `a.clear();` method in onClick() Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Set for CheckBox in xml file

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: didn't help:(
It seems it might be something wrong in OnClick

Comment: I have same problem and i put in xml file where is  CheckBox for clickable and focusable. This must work. Again try